OSLog sometimes shows error instead of including string
Logger().fault("Example: \(myStr, privacy: .public)")

Why do I get the following instead of the contents of myStr sometimes? myStr looks fine in the debugger and not like this.
Example: <decode: bad range for [%{public}s] got [offs:175 len:1219 within:0]>

The strings are confidential but nothing special really, just English letters, →, and line breaks. When a string fails to display, it does so consistently. But very similar strings display fine, including much longer ones.
